# Panel floating inside div

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a header, body and footer. There is also a chat panel displayed at the bottom of the page that floats when the page scrolls.

I've used `position:fixed; bottom:0px;` but the chat panel overlaps the page footer.

How can I make the panel stop from overlapping the footer? I tried putting the panel in the body's div but didn't work.

Here is some example code:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="body">
    <div>
      Body content...
    </div>
    <div style="position:fixed;bottom:0px;right:100px;border:solid 1px black;background-color:orange;">
      This is the chat panel
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer" style="background-color: gray;">This is the footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here two screenshots of the expected behaviour:
In mid page
[image: midpage]

and when reaching the bottom
[image: bottom]

Comment: Share some code please... Do you want the panel to float just above the footer or do you want to place the footer behind the panel?

Comment: @ThomasBormans the chat panel should NOT cover the footer. I've edited the question with a simplified version of the page code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work and do what you want it to do. You can probably optimise it so it scrolls smoothly together with the footer when reaching the bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/4cgyjpqt/3/

CSS:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 40px;
}
.panel {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:20px;
    right:100px;
    border:solid 1px black;
    background-color:orange;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
     var $win = $(window);

     $win.scroll(function () {
         if ($win.height() + $win.scrollTop() == $(document).height()) {
            // When the user is at the bottom of the page, get the footer height
             var footer = $('#footer').height();
             // set footer height as number of px from bottom
             $('.panel').css('bottom', footer);
         } else {
            // When the user is not at the bottom, set bottom back to 0px
             $('.panel').css('bottom', '0px');
         }
     });
 });
```

Comment: As I replied to Udit, the chat panel should hit the bottom of the page, unless it reaches the footer.

Comment: @algiogia I have changed my answer. This should do the trick.

Comment: That does the trick, but isn't there a way to have the chat div floating inside the "body" div? The reason I'm asking is because the footer can be expanded (does't have a fixed height).

Comment: @algiogia The location of the chat div is already inside the body div. I have altered the jQuery code so the footer can have a dynamic height.